# How do I port a simple 2D Monogame to MacOSX

Tags: monogame, macos, porting

I have made a simple Windows Monogame project (using the DirectX template).
What are the steps to port my game over to MacOSX?

If I need to change my Monogame project so that it uses a OpenGL template instead of the DirectX template please explain how.

Comment: From what I have seen, when you install monogame on a mac and you have a template ready for it. You can't compile for the mac on windows, and you can't compile for windows on mac

Comment: While I think I understand what you are saying, have you ported a Monogame game to MacOSX before and if you have could you give me the exact steps? Telling me that stuff could really help me out.

Comment: @Shiro is incorrect. You can compile for Mac on Windows. See [this post](http://gamasutra.com/blogs/MichaelHicks/20140623/219612/Converting_an_XNA4_Game_to_FNA.php). You can compile for all the platforms simultaneously in visual studio on Windows.

Comment: The projects for android/mac/linus/ios/windows are different. This is why there are different templates. The content pipeline also works differently for every platforms. This is why there are options for the content pipeline to select your target platform, so that the `.xnb`s are formatted for every platform properly. **Only the code is the same**, with a few minor changes in the input, the way you get the screen size etc.

Comment: @mklingen [monogame's developer Tom](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/448767) Quote: "For mac/iOS, you have to use Xamarin Business to do a Windows to Mac build. Plus you must have a mac machine that is separate from your windows machine, either through parallels on the mac or by physical separation." So, I suppose you first need to have a MAC and then Xamarin business licence. What you linked clearly says its "FNA" not monogame

Comment: FNA is a branch of Monogame, specifically to do cross-compilations from PC to Mac/Linux. I have done this myself without Xamarin Business or any other additional software.

Comment: @mklingen Oh I never heard about that. I don't see anything like that in their github

Comment: @mklingen Could you answer this question please?http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99104/question-about-installation-of-fna